# Why is my code crashing?

Tags: c, pointers

I've got a pretty basic question, why is my code crashing? I'm learning to use pointers and I really don't know why the code crashes after I enter the values of x1,x2,y1 and y2 (this happens in case 3 of the second switch). I've looked everywhere and I can't find a reason. I need to send the values entered in function menuLR, case 3 to the function DistDosPuntos, an then return the values to menuLR,case 3.

Here's my code.

Some of the code is in spanish, however it's not relevant to know how the code is working. In advance thanks for your help and patience, I know this is quite dumb, but I've tried several methods and haven't been able to either solve or understand the problem

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void menu1();
void menuLR();
void DistDosPuntos();

void menu1()
{
int a;
float m,x1,x2,y1,y2,k,v,d;  
printf("MENU PRINCIPAL\n");
printf("1.- La línea Recta \n");
printf("2.- La circunferencia \n");
printf("3.- Coordenaas Polares \n");
printf("4.- Salir\n");
scanf("%d",&a); 

switch(a)
{
    case 1: 
        menuLR(&m,&x1,&x2,&y1,&y2,&k,&v,&d);
    break;

    case 2 :
    // ; 
    break;

    case 3 :
    //; 
    break;

    case 4 :
    break ;
}

}

void menuLR (float *m,float*x1,float *x2,float *y1,float*y2,float*k,float         *v,float *d)
{   
int b;


printf("LA LINEA RECTA\n");
printf("1.- Ecuación de la recta dada su puendiente y un punto de la misma \n");
printf("2.- Ecuación de la recta que pasa por dos puntos\n");
printf("3.- Distancia entre dos puntos del plano \n");
printf("4.- Punto medio entre dos puntos del plano\n");
printf("5.- Perímetro y área de un triángulo en un plano\n");
printf("6.- Regresar al menú principal\n");
scanf("%d",&b); 

switch (b)
{
    case 1 : 
    printf("Introduzca la pendiente de la recta m y el punto P1(x1,y1)\n");
    printf("Introduzca m\n");
    scanf("%f",m);
    printf("Introduzca x1\n");
    scanf("%f",x1);
    printf("Introduzca y1\n");
    scanf("%f",y1);

    printf("La ecuación de la recta es:\n");
    printf("y-y1 = m(x-x1)\n");
    printf("Sustituyendo valores:\n");
    printf("y-%f = %f (x-%f) \n" ,*y1,*m,*x1);
    printf("Desarrollando y despejando:\n");
    *k = ((*m)*(*x1));
    printf("y-%f = %fx-%f)\n",*y1,*m,*k);
    *v= -*k+*y1;
    printf("y=%fx+(%f)\n",*m,*v);

    printf("La ecuación de la recta en la forma general 'y=mx+b' es:\n");
    printf("y=%fx+(%f)\n",*m,*v);
    break;

    case 2 :



    break;

    case 3 :
    printf("Introduzca el punto en el plano P1(X1,Y1)\n"); 
    printf("x1:");
    scanf("%f",x1);
    printf("y1:");
    scanf("%f",y1);
    printf("Introduzca el punto en el plano P2(X2,Y2)\n");
    printf("X2:\n");
    scanf("%f",x2);
    printf("Y2:\n");
    scanf("%f",y2);

    DistDosPuntos(&x1,&x2,&y1,&y2,&d);

    printf("La distancia entre los puntos P1 y P2 es:\n %f",*d);
    break;

    case 4 :
    // exit ; 
    break ;
    }
   }

void DistDosPuntos(float *x1,float *x2, float *y1, float *y2,float *d)
{
    *d = sqrt(pow((*x2-*x1),2) + pow((*y2-*y1),2));
}


int main()
{
int a,b;
float m,x1,y1,k,v,d,y2,x2;
menu1(&b,&x1,&y1,&x2,&y2,&m,&k,&v,&d);
DistDosPuntos(&x1,&x2,&y1,&y2,&d);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Time to learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: `DistDosPuntos(&x1,&x2,&y1,&y2,&d);` --> `DistDosPuntos(x1,x2,y1,y2,d);`

Comment: Crashing? Your program should show errors while compiling.

Comment: @SKD I think no, because OP is using same names for pointers passed to function and global variables. So compiler does not complains due to the local and global scope.

Comment: @LPs the call to menu1() in main() passes the wrong number of arguments

Comment: @samgak No, because of void menu1() is an _old-style_  function declaration that means: **_function that takes an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified type_**

Comment: BTW start using different names for different variable: if you have a global float x1, the function declaration shouldn't be `void foo (float *x1)` but, e.g., `void  foot( float *local_x1)`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are taking the address of a pointer and passing as a pointer in this section:

```
printf("Y2:\n");
scanf("%f",y2);
// wrong? x1,x2... are *float; Remove the &s
DistDosPuntos(&x1,&x2,&y1,&y2,&d);
```

The arguments of the function menuLR are are variables with the names x1, etc. These are of type (float *). They happen to have the same name, (though different types), than the variables in your main function. That's why in one case you need no &, whereas in the main function you do.

Comment: If you write something about local and global scopes of variables I'll upvote.

Comment: What do you think? The variables in the main function aren't global variables though, so I'm not sure how to work global scope into it.

Comment: OP code have same definition of main variables at the top of code, with global scope. BTW your edit is good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Indeed, I was taking the adress and passing it as a pointer. That did it, well, that and fixing other issues the code had. (I also was sending 4 values to a function that requested 5). as I said pretty dumb mistakes.